# The textarea on the meta site blocks right clicks

Tags: bug, editing

When I am editing a post on the main site, using any browser on my Mac, I am able to select a word, and use the right click to show a contextual menu.

> [image: screenshot]

When I do the same on the meta site, it doesn't work.

I took the screenshot on my Mac Mini running macOS 10.12, when using Google Chrome 53.0.2785.143, the same browser I am currently using to navigate every Stack Exchange site.

I tried on other meta sites where I am not a moderator, and I got the following result:

- It doesn't appear on https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/
- On https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ sometimes it appears